# Can not run maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, target, multi-module

We have existing maven project. I have imported it with m2eclipse plugin.But 
I can not run the project. Tomcat can not see resources(WAR files under target folder).
What am I missing? BTW we have multi-module project(2 WAR files).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add the tomcat server in your eclipse.
2. The maven project should be a web based project
3. You need to add the web project to the tomcat server.
4. You need to add J2EE Module Dependencies - Eclipse 3.3 ( To enable all library dependencies to be available at runtime to tomcat). Paths that point to your m2 repo & the lib files.
   It may be Java EE Dependencies in earlier versions.
   Both your projects needed to be added similarly.

Comment: Arun thanks for your response! Actually we have 5 modules.Two of them is war file. I couldn't do 2nd and 3rd steps.Maybe it depends on Eclipse version.(mine is eclipse-3.6)...Or is there other way to do these steps?

Comment: You should be able to see the globe icon in your eclipse.  To verify just create a web based project to see how it would look in eclipse. 
On step 3, Right click on your Tomcat Server in eclipse you should get the option to add. Here is a link with all maven archetypes

http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html
maven-archetype-webapp (A simple Java web application)